# Arduino Nano Max Current Draw best Motors

Tags: arduino-nano

I know that the Arduino Nano cannot source more than 40ma per pin. My question is there any type of motor or continuous rotation servo that I could use four of to make a robot without making the Nano shutdown. I would prefer the price to not exceed $10 in total.

Comment: Just add an transistor or mosfet. That way you can switch more that 40mA.

Comment: How would I do that. Could you provide a diagram. Also, could I do that with a PN222A or another common transistor?

Comment: PN222A can go upto 500mA. [Example](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-13-dc-motors/transistors) with diagram.

Comment: @Gerben - you should put that as an answer.